# Kotlin Загрузить и добавить картинки в массив

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso, android-resources

У меня есть массив картинок в ресурсах-они успешно добавляются в мой RecyclerView  через код

```
  image.setImageResource(List_dannix.Image_id)
```

Нужно: Загрузить изображения не из моих ресурсов ,а из интернета (Т.е. Картинка загружается и добавляется в массив)

В таком формате я пробовал , не сработало:(

```
var ArrayImage:MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()
         ArrayImage.add(Picasso.get().load(URL)) //не сработало(
```

Имею проблему только с картинками, код для текста рабочий:)

Comment: И не могло "сработать". Локальные ресурсы представлены их идентификаторами в виде целых чисел. Картинку из интернета нельзя запихнуть в целое число.

Comment: Ну я так и подумал , а как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать создать массив строк и записывать туда Uri ссылки или ресурсного изображения. Ну а дальше проверять если элемент массива является ссылкой, то загружаем через пикассо, если нет то получаем drawable из uri и загружаем через setImageDrawable

[пример как достать uri из drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6606163/7540461)

[пример как получить drawable из uri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16718935/7540461)